# Crystal Reports Omitting Data

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

This might be a pretty simple question but I'm a Crystal Reports newbie...I have a report where I want specific pages that have a corresponding column omitted. So for example say it has someone's name and information on every page, how would I use a column that for example has the state on it, to omit certain results, like I don't want any pages in the report generated from states that have the "state column" from the database equal to like "TX" or something. This isn't what I'm actually doing, but it's an example of the functionality I want.

I'm thinking it would be in either the group or record selection formulas but I'm not sure how to go about putting it together to not create a page for the results when a certain column is equal to a value.

-Thanks from a total Crystal Reports noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So each page of the report is one record in the result set (someone's name and information) and you want to exclude some pages based on the value of one of the columns?

Perhaps I'm not understanding the problem correctly but can't you just change the datasource query?

```
WHERE state <> 'TX'
```